# Python can open browsers... Can it open websites?

Tags: python, browser

In Linux, you can write a python script like down below to open a browser. Can you also open browser tabs to a specific link/website?

```
# Opens chromium in python
os.system("chromium")
```

Comment: If the `chromium` command takes a URL as a command-line argument, you can do that.

Comment: `os.startfile('somewebsite.com')`? would probably open the default webbrowser and go to the website

Comment: If the next question after "how can I go to a specific site" is "how do I extract content from the page or click on something", why not use Pyppeteer or Selenium? What are you trying to accomplish, please?

Comment: @ggorlen I am making a python script that will open all my stuff for school. Also, I found the answer myself: chromium websitedomainname

Comment: @Matiiss up above ^^

Comment: @Barmar up above ^^

Comment: Awesome, the context helps. Pyppeteer would be overkill. Feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to assist others with the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://example.com')
```

This uses [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html). You can also choose the browser:

```
path_to_browser = 'path to executable %s'
webbrowser.get(path_to_browser).open('http://example.com')
```

Comment: This works but I wanted to open Chromium. For your answer, I'll give an upvote though.

Comment: @JASFramework it opens with default browser usually but you can see on the link that you can choose the browser to use. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
# Opens chromium in python
os.system("chromium YourWebsiteName")
```

This will start a new window unless you already have one open.